# Get the value of a key after filtering with value in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. I am trying to get the value of a key after filtering it with a value. 
I first get the specific user with the room_num value "323" by using

```
uref.orderByChild("room_num").equalTo(room_num).once("value" ...
```

After I get the object of this user, I want to have access to his/her telephone number. But the code below does not give me what I need.

```
var uref = new Firebase('https://XXX.firebaseio.com/users');
uref.orderByChild("room_num").equalTo("323").once("value", function(data) {
      $scope.telephone = data.telephone;
      console.log($scope.telephone);
});
```

I also tried wrapping it with $firebaseArray.

Here is what my database looks like

```
users
  6GFbWBV9rINa3ZCDN45BgM1PO3o2
      email: "test@gmail.com"
      name: "Mark"
      room_num: "323"
      telephone: "72839202"
```

[My database looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUyzv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is passed a snapshot. The snapshot will have a child for each entry that matches the query. To access the data within the child snapshot, you need to call `val()`:

```js
uref.orderByChild("room_num").equalTo("323").once("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var data = childSnapshot.val();
    $scope.telephone = data.telephone;
    console.log($scope.telephone);
  });
});
```

Comment: It works when I changed it to `once("child_added")` It prints out `undefined` for  `once("value")`.

Comment: `console.log(data)` prints out `Object
6GFbWBV9rINa3ZCDN45BgM1PO3o2:
Object
email: "test@gmail.com"
      name: "Mark"
      room_num: "323"
      telephone: "72839202"`

Comment: Yep, there was an error in the answer. In this situation, the `value` callback receives a snapshot that contains children that match the query and you can enumerate the snapshot's children using `forEach`.